# Struggling with custom Dojo build for a Range Slider

Tags: javascript, dojo, slider

I'm struggling to create a custom build for a Range Slider.  My slider works fine when I use the downloaded dojo.xd.js file from google.  When I use the custom builder and replace the dojo.xd.js file with the builder output I get no range slider. Do I need to include dojo.js in addition to the custom built file, which I am doing?

Here is my profile for the custom build:

```
 dependencies ={

   layers:  [
       {
       name: "myDojo.js",
       dependencies: [
        "dijit.form.Slider",
        "dojox.form.RangeSlider"]
       }
   ],

   prefixes: [
       [ "dijit", "../dijit" ],
       [ "dojox", "../dojox" ]
   ]

 };
```

When I open my page I get the following errors.  I'm running this locally. No server.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Projects/dcardcjs/trunk/DRandomizerJS/source/selector/acme.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
dojo.js:15 Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
CardClass.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: dojo is not defined
```

Thanks for the help.

edit:  Here's my page code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Kingdom Builder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css"/>
    <script src="dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
        dojo.require("dojox.form.RangeSlider");
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url(../dijit/RangeSlider.css);
    </style>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="expansions.js"></script>
    <script src="CardClass.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
```

Comment: Can you post your page's code ?

Comment: @philippe  Page code added.  Can I post anything else that will help?  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm...  what version of dojo are you building ? It looks like someone already had your problem : see http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Dojo-1-71rc-build-xDomain-problems-td3573742.html

Comment: It's the latest version.  Actually it's no longer an issue for me, but maybe someone else is interested in the solution.  I changed to the jquery range slider.  It was easy to use offline as that's how it's shipped, less bloat, I'm already using jquery in my project, I don't want to have to become a dojo expert to use their widgets.  I might give them a shot again later if I don't need to run offline.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to include the acme selector  in the build, you must include it in the build script.
Second, to include the base dojo libs, include 'dojo/dojo'. Thirdly, I noticed in your html file, you have a script tag importing 'dojo.js', make sure to change that to what you have named your layer: 'myDojo.js' :) Hope this helps someone out there even if you have moved on to jquery.

```
dependencies ={

layers:  [
   {
       name: "myDojo.js",
       dependencies: [
           'dojo/dojo',
           'dojo/selector/acme',
           'dijit.form.Slider',
           'dojox.form.RangeSlider'
       ]
   }
],

prefixes: [
   [ "dijit", "../dijit" ],
   [ "dojox", "../dojox" ]
]

};
```